# Process chemical formula in elixir

Tags: parsing, recursion, elixir

I would like to count atoms in provided String. So far I am able to get a result like this:

```
iex(1)> Chemistry.tokenize("In[Cu(SO4)2H2]3O")
[{:atom, "In", 1}, {:bracket, "Cu(SO4)2H2", 3}, {:atom, "O", 1}]
```

I would like to ask you if you if you think that this is a good approach? Tokenize and then recursivelly process list? If yes, how should be the result treated next? My idea is evaluate every bracket fragment until it is only atom. But I am not sure about implementation. Thank you for any advice.

Here is a code I have written so far.

```
defmodule Chemistry do
  @moduledoc """
  Documentation for Chemistry.
  """

  @atom_count_regex ~r/(?<atom>^[A-Z][a-z]?)(?<count>\d*)(?<tail>.*)/
  @round_bracket_regex ~r/^[(](?<bracket>.*)[)](?<count>\d*)(?<tail>.*)/
  @square_bracket_regex ~r/^[[](?<bracket>.*)[]](?<count>\d*)(?<tail>.*)/
  @curly_bracket_regex ~r/^[{](?<bracket>.*)[}](?<count>\d*)(?<tail>.*)/

  def tokenize(""), do: []
  def tokenize(chunk) do
      cond do
        Regex.match?(@atom_count_regex, chunk) ->
          %{"atom" => atom, "count" => count, "tail" => tail} = Regex.named_captures(@atom_count_regex, chunk)
          if count == "" do
            [{:atom, atom, 1} | tokenize(tail)]
          else
            [{:atom, atom, String.to_integer(count)} | tokenize(tail)]
          end
        String.starts_with?(chunk, ["{", "[", "("]) ->
          cond do
            String.starts_with?(chunk, "{") ->
              process_bracket(chunk, @curly_bracket_regex)
            String.starts_with?(chunk, "[") ->
              process_bracket(chunk, @square_bracket_regex)
            String.starts_with?(chunk, "(") ->
              process_bracket(chunk, @round_bracket_regex)
          end
      end
  end

  defp process_bracket(chunk, regex) do
    %{"bracket" => bracket, "count" => count, "tail" => tail} = Regex.named_captures(regex, chunk)
    if count == "" do
      [{:bracket, bracket, 1} | tokenize(tail)]
    else
      [{:bracket, bracket, String.to_integer(count)} | tokenize(tail)]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The approach seems good to me. Can you post the code so someone can try to help in the next step?

Comment: Just a quick check: is `41` the answer to `In[Cu(SO4)2H2]3O` ?

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff thanks for this check. Nope. The expected result would be %{"In" => 1, "Cu" => 3, "S" => 6, "O" => 25, "H" => 6}. Sorry for not providing this information.

Comment: Can you try to split your `tokenize` into smaller functions? For now it doesn't say too much what it does. Also your regexps are quite similar - can you rewrite them to see common part and append it to prefixes? Also your 'process_bracket` should be splitted -`Regex.named_captures` could go to the different function and `process_bracket` would accept map and brancing on `count` would be on signature level.

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this, I tend to use a recursive parser like this:

```
defmodule Parser do
  @open_p '(['
  @close_p ')]'
  @lower ?a..?z
  @upper ?A..?Z

  def parse(string) do
    parse(string, [], "")
  end

  defp parse("", stack, ""), do: stack
  defp parse("", stack, buffer), do: [buffer | stack]

  defp parse(<<ch::8>> <> tail, stack, "") when ch in @open_p, 
    do: parse(tail, [[] | stack], "")
  defp parse(<<ch::8>> <> tail, stack, buffer) when ch in @open_p, 
    do: parse(tail, [[buffer] | stack], "")
  # ...
end
```

If you build tuples for each atom like `{"H", 6}`, then its each iterate over it with an `Enum.reduce` to build the final map.

Another FYI note, the following code form your question:

```
      cond do
        String.starts_with?(chunk, "{") ->
          process_bracket(chunk, @curly_bracket_regex)
        String.starts_with?(chunk, "[") ->
          process_bracket(chunk, @square_bracket_regex)
        String.starts_with?(chunk, "(") ->
          process_bracket(chunk, @round_bracket_regex)
      end
```

could benefit form pattern matching like the following if you reversed the order of parameters in `process_bracket`:

```
case chunk do
  "{" <> _ -> @curly_bracket_regex
  "[" <> _ -> @square_bracket_regex
  "(" <> _ -> @round_bracket_regex
end
|> process_bracket(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to explicitly recurse if you follow the algorithm I sketch out below - illustrated by your example:
Initial state:

```
In[Cu(SO4)2H2]3O
```

After each lower case letter place a `:`

```
In[Cu:(SO4)2H2]3O
```

After each upper case letter not followed by a lowercase letter place a `:`

```
In:[Cu:(S:O:4)2H:2]3O:
```

After each `:` not followed by a number append `1`

```
`In:1[Cu:1(S:1O:4)2H:2]3O:1`
```

For each number `K` after a bracket *internalize* as follows
modify each internal `letter:number` to `letter:K*number`

```
In:1[Cu:3*1(S:3*2*1*O:3*2*4)H:3*2]O:1
```

eliminate all brackets

```
In:1Cu:3*1S:3*2*1O:3*2*4H:3*2O:1
```

split on number letter transition

```
In:1
Cu:3*1
S:3*2*1
O:3*2*4
H:3*2
O:1
```

then do the math & collect terms using elixir map functions ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sure, this is something what would work. However, is this really a functional approach to tackle such a problem?

Comment: In elixir regexp  (which are most of the above algorithm) are implemented functionally so yes.  The point is there is no need for recursion just the `for each` iteration. Which is the question you seemed to ask.